# Conductor induced current and electronagnetic wave phase

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

For an electron gas in metal,the current induced by external electromagnetic wave should take the following form:

$$mv'(t)=qE\sin(\omega t)$$
$$v(t)=A \cos(\omega t)$$

J be induced current,

$$J=nev(t)$$
$$J=j\cos(\omega t)$$

A,j are arbitrary constants,n=charge density.

Hence,the induced current is out of phase with electromagnetic wave.But in case of a conductor,the current is simply
$$J=\sigma E$$ ,s be the conductivity.Here this is perfectly in phase.Where lies the fallacy?Is not the electric response due to the movement of free electrons?

Answer (score 0):

$J = \sigma E$ is a relation between complex amplitudes, in this case $\sigma$ will be pure imaginary - giving you the 90 degree phase difference.

Comment: Actually when we solve maxwell equations in conductor,we do take sigma as real.That's why I asked the question,and in case of ionised gas,we treat sigma as imaginary.